# JDK/JRE installer not working on x64

Tags: java, installation, 64-bit

So I began developing Java applications on my laptop a few weeks ago, and I've been doing so on my laptop since then... But now when I try to install the JDK on my PC, it doesn't install (as in, I double click on the JDK[version].exe and the Install Wizard doesn't even show up). -- and yes, I have the JRE installed. I'm very confused and frustrated... I'd really appreciate if someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong (and, yes, I've already tried reinstalling the JRE).

Comment: Check that the JDK installer is right for your OS (Windows, Linux, Mac...) and architecture (x86, x64).

Comment: try to use eclipse or netbeans in first place (to write your first hello world, etc), then try to install the java sdk latter.

Comment: First install the JDK, then install the IDE you need/want.

Comment: I have a 64-bit OS & I'm trying to install the x64 JDK -- and it is not working. The wizard does not show up. Any ideas?

Comment: Do other installers show up (e.g. for other applications) or is it just for the JDK?

Comment: The JRE worked fine when I installed it. Other Java apps work fine as well. It's just the JDK. ;/ Exact same setup procedure and OS as my laptop, and the JDK wizard just isn't even opening. Is there any way to get a .rar version of the JDK so I can use javac?

Comment: I have download the JDK installer for x64 just now and it worked. Check that the installer has been downloaded correctly , maybe try to copy/paste it in your laptop and run it there. If the problem is not in the installer, try to restart your PC and run the installer.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I reinstalled the JRE completely and restarted my PC after disabling firewalls, and everything worked perfectly upon boot! Might have just been a a few faulty JRE installs due to firewalls :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Download the JDk from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u25-download-346242.html). Please check the **product/File description** which matches your PC as download it.

Comment: I have a 64-bit OS & I'm trying to install the x64 JDK -- and it is not working. The wizard does not show up. Any ideas?

Comment: Since x64 is for 64 bit, check the OS, if its the same.

Answer (score 48):

I had the same problem, tried installing JDK 8u111 and 8u112 in both x64 and i586 flavors on Windows 7 x64 and it seemed that nothing worked.

Checking in *Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application* as suggested by Felix Christi showed that the Windows Installer has actually completed all the installations.

So I went to *Program Files\Java* and found all of the 4 JDK installations sitting nicely side-by-side, without me even getting a single confirmation message. Have you checked that the installation did really fail in your case?

Comment: Same thing happened to me. I kept double-clicking, nothing would open, even tried running as Administrator, and finally looked in _Program Files\Java_ (after reading this post) and saw that it had in fact installed, just with no dialog or confirmation at all. Seriously, Oracle? Who does that???

Comment: me too!  seriously this is the dumbest thing i've ever seen.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: Exactly the same problem here, even in September of 2017. I agree with @Michi

Answer (score 3):

First of all, please check your PC operating system. If it is windows (thats what I guess by your question detail about wizard), try to see system information (check for 64 bit). If it is not, please try to install x86 (32 bit) JDK.

If it is x64 (64 bit) then, try to run with "Run as administrator" option by right clicking it.

If it is not working either way, then please check the system log from Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer and see what is going around on installation.

In the worst case, for work around, just install 32 bit JDK, it should work fine in 64 bit OS.

After all this, if you are successful in installing, please follow this link to configure JDK

[JDK STEP BY STEP](http://www.javatutorialhub.com/install-java.html)

Comment: OP's problem is that he can't execute the JDK installer

Comment: @Luiggi: Always wondered what OP is? Can you expand it ?

Comment: OP had problems installing the JDK, maybe for a bad JRE installation or firewalls, but at last he/she could do it by his/her own. This kind of questions are kinda hard to answer (PC OS, architecture, configuration, antivirus, firewalls, and on...) so I don't think there is a right answer in this case, still, as OP has said, he/she has installed the JDK in laptop first, so the step by step was not an answer.

Comment: @Ajj "OP" means "Original Poster" which in this context means the author of the question.

Answer (score 3):

If nothing shows up when you launch your JDK installer, it is likely performing a **silent install**.  Whether or not your installer runs silently is controlled by Java's [System Runtime Configuration File](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/config.html#system_runtime_config_file).  On Windows, that file can be found here:

> Windows: %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Oracle\Java\java.settings.cfg
>
> The value of the environment variable %ALLUSERSPROFILE% is typically
>   C:\ProgramData.

Change the line `INSTALL_SILENT=Enable` to `INSTALL_SILENT=Disable`, and try launching your installer again.  The Install Wizard should appear as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, tried installing JDK 8u111 and 8u112 in both x64 and i586 flavors on Windows 7 x64 and it seemed that nothing worked.

Checking in Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Event Viewer > Windows Logs > Application as suggested by Felix Christi showed that the Windows Installer has actually completed all the installations.

So I went to Program Files\Java and found all of the 4 JDK installations sitting nicely side-by-side, without me even getting a single confirmation message. Have you checked that the installation did really fail in your case?

--- I'm having the same issue as the above... it seemed like jdk is being installed in the background... this is frustrating because I'm waiting for the jdk window to ask me for a path to install this... I would like to install it on a separate folder on my C drive. I've set the environment variables and I can't figure out what's wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and eventually I solved it next way. All that I was needed to do was turn off Smart Screen in windows settings

If you don't familiar with Smart Screen You can try to read in google what is it and also I attached screenshot with my settings. Now all is ok

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it turned out to be that my disk was almost full (500MB free space left). The installer(8u141) would just exit without any message, and I had no error in the Event Viewer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case jdk1.8.0_144 was installed SILENTLY from a distributive jdk-8u144-windows-x64.exe. It was a surprise. (OS Windows 7 64)

Comment: Mikhail, when answering it's usually handy to explain the steps you took to resolve the issue, currently even if you are right people coming along later wouldn't be able to fix it based your current answer, oh and welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem. Nothing was happening, just saw installer file in processes.
Steps, which helped me:

1. Moved installer to C:\ directory;
2. Turned off DrWeb;
3. Turned on autostart Java via msconfig.

Windows 7 x64

Comment: These steps seem very specific to your individual case. The question doesn't mention anything called 'DrWeb' (which, by the way, looks like a highly untrustworthy 'anti-virus' application!), and as it's nearly 6 years since the question was asked, it seems likely that the original problem is a bit irrelvant now!

Answer (score -3):

In my case I went to the Event Viewer and I got this message, same message I got when I tried to run installer from the downloads folder

[image]

Comment: please add message as text, not as image and fix your post